# create Nested index structure SOLR

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, nested, document

I want to create nested index structure with SOLR import handler. I am using Solr -7.2 ,I have created data-config.xml
(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5147),

```
<document>
        <entity name="PARENT" query="select * from parent">
          <field column="id" />
          <field column="title" />
          <field column="type_s" />
          <entity child="true" name="CHILD" query="select * from child where 
           parent_id='${PARENT.id}'">
                <field column="id" />
                <field column="post" />
                    <field column="parent_id" />
          </entity>
    </entity>   
 </document>
```

but I am not getting nested index document as result of below query,
http://xyzhost:8983/solr/myCollection/select?fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=title:%22test%22]&q=*:*
What I am missing here ?

Imported document looks like below,

```
` "response":{"numFound":6,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "post":"dev1",
    "parent_id":"1",
    "id":"1",
    "_version_":1608402260456374272},
  {
    "post":"dev3",
    "parent_id":"1",
    "id":"3",
    "_version_":1608402260456374272},
  {
    "id":"1",
    "title":"test1",
    "_version_":1608402260456374272},
  {
    "post":"dev2",
    "parent_id":"2",
    "id":"2",
    "_version_":1608402260460568576},
  {
    "post":"dev4",
    "parent_id":"4",
    "id":"4",
    "_version_":1608402260460568576},
  {
    "id":"2",
    "title":"test2",
    "_version_":1608402260460568576}]
```

}}`

Comment: What does your imported documents (i.e. actual in-the-index-documents) look like?

Comment: @MatsLindh have added imported document structure. Please check.